# To display legend of the chart outside the canvas of the chart in highcharts

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

Below is the my legend setting for highchart graph

```
legendenabled = true
layout = vertical 
floating = true
y = 100
x = 0
align = right
verticalAlign = bottom
backgroundColor = #FCFFC5
marginBottom = 220
borderColor = #C98657
```

I want to get legend box below the chart, I guess its getting fixed to chart canvas, I have used Highchart API to get that background sky animation,this legend I have read from INI file and pass to Highchart API in the form of JSON Format,
Any idea...what I am messing with....???,
Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: You need to disable floating option

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
legend:
{
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    floating: true
}
```

Mainly, [floating](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.floating) will do, I guess.

Hoe it helps.